# Pyrocms if condition is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyro

this is my pyro cms code.

```
{{ images }}
  {{ if default == 1 }}
      <div><img src='{{ src }}'/>
  {{ endif }}
{{ /images }}
```

this condition is not working when i try to print default value.

```
{{ images }}
    {{ default }}
{{ images }}
```

i have two images in array. and output is return.

0 1

in array already have a default value 1. but condition is not working.

please help where i made mistake.

thank you.

Comment: Did you try `{{ if default == '1' }}`

Comment: @DamienPirsy yes but not work.